# Multiple Upload Providers Strapi

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, strapi

I need to enable different upload providers in Strapi based on the upload mime type. I would like images  to go to cloudinary, while attachments like .docx or .pdf should be uploaded to strapi local folder to be hosted. I have configured cloudinary in `plugins.js` and it works, but not the local upload.

Answer (score 1):

I developed a plugin because had same need.

You can check here:
https://github.com/msoler75/strapi-provider-upload-multiple-provider

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).